# Request for member 'capitalLabel' in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

getting above error in the following line

```
cell.capitalLabel.text= [capitals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: your cell has no member called capitalLabel. Post more code. The interface (.h) of the cell for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `capitalLabel` object before you can assign it's value.

Do this:

```
UILabel *capitalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] 
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, width, height)];

capitalLabel.text = [capitals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.contentView addSubview:capitalLabel];
```

Comment: @Zaraki kenpachi, if it works then you need to accept the answer.